# Increasing the size of a filesystem in AIX - chfs and df commands

Tags: filesystems, size, aix

the command `df /` displays the following output on my host.

`Filesystem    512-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd4         5177344   1065096   80%    13676     9% /`

according to the manpage of df, by default all sizes are displayed in number of 512 blocks. Therefore, my / filesystem has 1065096 512-blocks empty. Now say I want to add one more block of 512 bytes to the filesystem, I will use the chfs command to increase the size of the filesystem. Below:

`chfs -a size=+1 /`

the man page of chfs says that sizes can be increased in number of 512 byte blocks if the number is not followed by M or G. Here is what happened when I ran the above mentioned command.

`$ df /`

`Filesystem    512-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd4         5177344   1065096   80%    13676     9% /`

`$ chfs -a size=+1 /
Filesystem size changed to 5177344`

`$ df /`

`Filesystem    512-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd4         5177344   1065096   80%    13676     9% /`

`$ expr 1065096 \- 999568
65528`

Can someone explain how instead of increasing by one 512 block, the size increased by 127 512 blocks?

Comment: I'm not sure your cutnpaste was correct.  Before the chfs, your filesystem showed 5177344 512byte blocks.  After the chfs, your filesystem still shows 5177344 byte blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you messed up with copy-paste. I will explain how it works and you apply this to your environment.

When you're using chfs -a size=+1 the command increases your LV by one block but the thing is that you can only increase LV by some amount of PPs. For example if you have PP size configured to 64Mb you'd have your LV automatically increased by 64*1024=65536 blocks.

So issue a command "lsvg ", check "PP size" and count.